# PHP: Slowing down a website

Tags: php, mysql

Does  continuously logging in and out of a PHP website make it slow down or crash (for example with a bot or a program)?

Just asking, so I know if I should add a CAPTCHA on login page.

Comment: Please dont desturb users with captcha on the login page, it is used to get rid of bots when using forms in other ways..

Comment: @CTravel I don't see any harm in a captcha or something else after x logins in x time.

Comment: CAPTCHA for register, and at the most a verify if the user gets too many incorrect logins.

Comment: Like Dave says,, when too many incorrect logins..

Comment: What does the second sentence in this question have to do with the first sentence?  Are you asking if many actions will cause the site to slow down over time, or if many concurrent actions would cause it to slow down temporarily?  What do many actions have to do with adding a CAPTCHA?

Comment: Or just throttle it. If they log in 10 times rapidly, intentionally make the site slow down for that IP address or user or some other criteria. Eventually, after a large amount of failed logins, just block that account or IP for some time.

Comment: A CAPTCHA wouldn't stop a "DoS attack" from a bot...

Comment: i know what a DDOS is. But some guy said that he kept logging in and out of a server with a bot like 500 times a min, and the server began to lagg and take 5 seconds to load a page.  So am just wondering if its true, if yes, i will add a capatcha

Comment: this wouldn't stop those attacks. You'd have to block certain IPs with a firewall that filters requests before they are being transported to the destination server behind the firewall. As an example.

Comment: @user2421030 There's nothing special about a login function here, except that it might be a more likely target for repeated requests (i.e. brute force cracks). Without proper caching, the bot could hit your homepage 500 times/second with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, continually and rapidly doing any action on a website (including logging in) will make it slow down for other users. This is called a [Denial of Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack, and is used frequently by malicious individuals. Crashes will only happen in extreme cases, but can occur.

Comment: it strongly depends on the amount and frequency of actions... 10 logins per minute is no harm at all. If you have 200'000 login attempts on a small, shared server, you will probably run into a bottleneck.

Comment: I've edited my response to better reflect the scale required. I hadn't realized I didn't properly communicate this.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys :) Does it also count if a bot tries to log in with wrong username and pass ?

Comment: And it's worth mentioning, in this context, that a CAPTCHA would not prevent it.

Comment: It's any action. Whenever a client (user, bot, etc) sends a query to the server (view a page, log in, etc.), the server has to run computations - your PHP code - in order to do what the user requested. But it can only do these computations so fast, so if someone is constantly sending queries over and over again, the server's going to go slower because it's spending some of its time helping that user instead of helping legitimate users.